# What characteristics does my dataset of time series need for machine learning forecasting with python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, dataset, forecasting

I want to create a dataset that can be used for forecasting with different machine learning algorithms (like LSTM). The dataset is a time series that contains one value per day. For my purpose it is important that the characteristics of the data changes from having a trend in the first 9 months to trend+seasonality for the last 3 months of a year (significantly higher demand around 1. and 15. of a month).

First, I created random data with a trend for one period and added the higher demand in the last 3 months manually in Excel.

[Plot of first period](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhP1v.png)

Now, I need to add the following periods and I wrote this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
from random import seed
from random import random
from numpy.random import randint



excel_file = 'Dataset 1.3.xls'
datensatz =pd.read_excel(excel_file)


demand5=pd.read_excel(excel_file,sheetname=4) 
b=demand5['value']
pnext=[]
endeLast=1500


ALL=[]
plast=list(b)   
for j in range(19,25):
    seed(j)
    pnext=[] 
    pnext.append(endeLast)


    if j % 2 ==0: 
        for i in range(0,365):

                zahl=random()
                if zahl < 0.4:
                        movement = randint(30,150)
                elif zahl <0.7:
                        movement = randint(-70,30)
                else:
                        movement = randint(150,250)

                next = endeLast + plast[i]+ movement

                pnext.append(next)
                ALL.append(next)

                plast[i]=next

    else:
        for i in range(0,365):

                zahl=random()
                if zahl < 0.4:
                        movement = randint(50,250)
                elif zahl <0.7:
                        movement = randint(30,130)
                else:
                        movement = randint(50,200)

                next = endeLast + plast[i]+ movement

                pnext.append(next)
                ALL.append(next)

                plast[i]=next

    endeLast=plast[-1] 

plt.plot(ALL,'-')
pyplot.show(ALL)
```

Is looks like this:
[plot of 6 new periods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdR5B.png)

I have the feeling the periods look way too similar (even a simple Holt-Winter forecasting method could do the job).

How can I change the characteristics of the dataset to make the periods less alike AND at the same time I still want the dataset to be useful as training data for my machine learning forecast?

Or do you have any other suggestion on how to create more training data from one period of data?

Thank you so much, I'm very new to python and any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you want the dataset to be useful to just play with algorithms or for real forecasting (to train pre-train a model)?

Comment: I only need the dataset to be useful for the algorithms I want to try out.